# As UITableviewCell count more than 10 and if I click on top of button it automatically click in last of UITableViewCell button. any idea?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my `UITableViewCell` have button `AddToCart` buttons. As if my `UITableView` data is more than 10 means I have to scroll to see all data. So now if I will on first button of first `UITableViewCell` as I scroll down to see all records of tableview than automatically last or second last button will also click I am unable to find the problem why this is happening

I am implementing first time this type of functionality so got stuck to resolve the problem

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 13
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tblCell") as! ProductTableViewCell
    cell.btnAddToCart.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.btnAddToCart.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addToCartDell(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}
```

This function is used for hide and show Add To Cart button option.

```
@objc func addToCartDell(sender: UIButton) {
    let tagVal = sender.tag
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: tagVal, section: 0)
    if let cell = tblProduct.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ProductTableViewCell {
        cell.btnAddToCart.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cells are reused. You don't save the hidden state of the cell so when a cell is reused the latest state is preserved.

In Swift the most efficient and reliable solution is to save the state *added to cart* in the data model and use a callback closure to update the UI in `cellForRow`.

In the data model add a property `addedToCart`, it's assumed that a custom struct or class is used as data model

```
var addedToCart = false
```

In `ProductTableViewCell` add the callback variable and an IBAction. Connect the IBAction to the button

```
var callback : (()->())?

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender : UIButton) {
   callback?()
}
```

In the controller in `cellForRow` handle the callback, `products` represents the data source array

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tblCell") as! ProductTableViewCell
    let product = products[indexPath.row]
    cell.btnAddToCart.isHidden = product.addedToCart
    cell.callback = {
        product.addedToCart = true
        cell.btnAddToCart.isHidden = true
    }
    return cell
}
```

No tags, no target/action, no protocols, no extra work in `willDisplayCell` .

Comment: I like your solution! I was sure you had to implement a protocol to handle buttons inside rows but you just thought me something really powerful. Maybe I was overcomplicating it with my approach... or do you think it still can be a good one (with your expertise)?

Comment: It depends. The callback solution is discouraged for example if the cells can be moved around so the index path can change without calling `cellForRow`.

Comment: @vadian There's nothing wrong with using the callback solution in of itself. The problem is when people rely on using a tag to hold the row number or give the cell its indexPath. The callback can be written properly without either of those things. Of course your answer is a great way too.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is turning up because we re-user same cell for displaying any further rows that was not visible yet.

you may implement this method to correct the display of any further cells

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
            willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, 
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Customize the cell as you want it to appear in this delegate method. This delegate method is called just before the cell is displayed, so you can do any customization here and it will turn up in the UI as per your customization.

If we go deep in to implementation.
 
There must be a model that keeps the state `addedToCart` in this model on basis of the button tapped in a particular row and use this same model's `addedToCart` (`model.addedToCart`) to show hide the button in delegate method.

Comment: Sanjay Mishra - Though this approach will solve your problem, however I would also recommend the way @vadian have suggested in his answer.

Comment: This leaves out all of the important details of keeping track of which cells should have the button displayed or not.

Comment: @rmaddy - I think that details need to be kept tracked in a model and that model itself will be used here in this delegate method as well to show hide button.

Comment: Right but it is those details that should be in your answer. Right now your answer doesn't really help at all. It just gives a really vague recommendation with no details.

Comment: @rmaddy - Added the details as per suggestion. Thanks for your valuable suggestion.